# Scaling of a complex vector using SSE

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, sse2

I want to apply SSE instructions to a vector containing complex numbers. Without SSE instructions, I can do it with the following code. However, when I apply SSE instructions, I don't know how to get the calculated real and imaginary part back to the array. How can I solve this?

```
complex double * complexScaling(complex double *input, double c, int length) 
{
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    input[i] = c*input[i];
  }
  return input;
}

complex double * complexScalingSSE(complex double *input, double c, int length) 
{
  __m128d multiplier,real,imag;
  multiplier = _mm_set1_pd(c);
  for(int i=0; i<length; i+=2) {
    real = _mm_set_pd(creal(input[i]),creal(input[i+1]));
    real = _mm_mul_pd(real, multiplier);
    imag = _mm_set_pd(cimag(input[i]),cimag(input[i+1]));
    imag = _mm_mul_pd(imag, multiplier);
  }
  return input;
}
```

Comment: What is your SSE level? There are several instruction sets indictated by CPUID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 4.1, 4.2, AVX, AVX2, FMA3, FMA4, BMI, BMI2, ... I ask that, because calculating complex numbers with FMAx is a piece of cake...

Comment: use [_mm_store*](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_store), either _mm_storeu_pd or _mm_store_pd

Comment: It has to be compatible with SSE2

Comment: Anything that looks like `set(var, var)` will generate really annoying code. The only safe set is with constant arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
complex double * complexScalingSSE(complex double *input, double c, int length)
{
    const __m128d vc = _mm_set1_pd(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        __m128d v = _mm_loadu_pd((double *)&input[i]);  // load one complex double
        v = _mm_mul_pd(v, vc);                          // scale it
        _mm_storeu_pd((double *)&input[i], v);          // store it
    }
    return input;
}
```

You might want to try loop unrolling by a factor of 2 (but note that for large vectors this routine may well be I/O bound):

```
complex double * complexScalingSSE(complex double *input, double c, int length)
{
    const __m128d vc = _mm_set1_pd(c);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= length - 2; i += 2)
    {
        __m128d v1 = _mm_loadu_pd((double *)&input[i]); // load two complex doubles
        __m128d v2 = _mm_loadu_pd((double *)&input[i + 1]);
        v1 = _mm_mul_pd(v1, vc);                        // scale them
        v2 = _mm_mul_pd(v2, vc);
        _mm_storeu_pd((double *)&input[i], v1);         // store them
        _mm_storeu_pd((double *)&input[i + 1], v2); 
    }
    if (i < length)                                     // handle odd element at end
    {
        __m128d v = _mm_loadu_pd((double *)&input[i]);  // load one complex double
        v = _mm_mul_pd(v, vc);                          // scale it
        _mm_storeu_pd((double *)&input[i], v);          // store it
    }
    return input;
}
```

Note also that a decent compiler should auto-vectorize your original routine, in which case you won't see any benefit from hand-coded SSE.

Comment: Yup, [gcc5 auto-vectorizes this just fine with SSE2](https://godbolt.org/g/WISDUa), even without `-ffast-math`.  Even gcc 4.9.2 doesn't seem to manage it, though.  Clang as usual unrolls it a reasonable amount.  (Only clang 3.6 and newer auto-vectorize.)

Comment: gcc 4.9.2 seems to need `-ffast-math` before it will vectorize this (it's not clear why that should be the case though).

Comment: Perhaps it just gets scared because there are floats and float optimizations are scary

Comment: How would I unroll by a factor of 2?

Comment: @Nils: just do two loads, two mutiplies and two stores for each loop iteration (using two separate temporary variables, e.g. v1, v2), and increment i by 2 instead of 1.